# Sbt Assembly Include Conf Files inside the JAR

Tags: scala, jar, sbt-assembly

I'm using the sbt assembly plugin to create a JAR file and I have the following folder structure:

```
src
 -main
  -scala
  -resources
    -application.conf
```

Now, when I do

```
sbt clean assembly
```

I can see in the produced Jar file that the application.conf file is included. I have two questions:

1. Why is the inluded application.conf not inside the resources folder in the final Jar, but rather it is on the top level as shown below (the contents of the Jar)

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x    3 joe  staff   102B May 16 21:03 com/
   -rw-r--r--    1 joe  staff   187B Mar  4  2016 library.properties
   drwxr-xr-x    3 joe  staff   102B May 16 21:03 typesafe/
   ```
2. How can I load this application.conf by setting a System.property? For example., I want to be able to load the application.conf by setting a System property like:

   `System.setProperty("config.file", "application.default.conf")`

With this I could control from outside (while running the jar file), which config file to use. When I tried this, I got a NulPointerException:

```
val someConfigFile = Option(System.getProperty("config.file"))
ConfigFactory.parseURL(getClass.getResource(someConfigFile.get)) // NullPointerException happens here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that the resources folder is like a src folder and so the content is copied, not the folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I needed to do so that the config file inside the jar could be loaded based on what I specify from outside!

```
  val is = new InputStreamReader(getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$cfgFile"))
  ConfigFactory.parseReader(is).resolve()
```